# Specifying the frequencies of nouns in text using java

Tags: java, regex, nlp, text-processing

I have a file contains the words attached with POS tags such as

```
Tom/NNP went/VBP to/IN the/DT stadium/NN ....etc
```

I need to know the frequency of all nouns contains in this file. So, the output might be

```
stadium     12 
football    20
player      13
```

where these numbers are the times of numbers these nouns occur in the text. How can I do this in java?

Comment: By writing a program that uses a Map<String, Integer> in it?

Comment: Start by reading the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html), and come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: So you need to match all words that have `/NN` after them and count them?

Comment: Use HashMap<String,Integer> where key will be nouns and value will be count. Check if key already present or not, if not then add key (noun) with value 1 otherwise increment the value by 1.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the reply! Actually I have no problem with reading or writing to a file! I am just asking about the mechanism to get the final output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a map from Strings (nouns) to integers (the count). Loop through each word in the file. Examine the part of the word after the '/', and if it is a noun, put it in the map with a "1" value if it isn't already in there, or add 1 to the existing value. Then iterate through the map, printing out the key/value pairs.